# How can user update their post in django rest UpdateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my Serializer class:

```
class CountSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Count
        fields = ('id','userId', 'channelId', 'rate')
```

This is urls.py to access the view

```
path('count/<int:pk>', CountlListView.as_view()),
```

This is my Views.py

```
class CountlListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CountSerializers
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userId = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = Count.objects.filter(userId=userId)
        print(userId)
        return queryset
```

If the user id 1 then the url will return all the post associated with user in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,                //a post id
        "userId": 1,            //user id
        "channelId": 2,         //another channeel id for which user vote
        "rate": 6               // rate(a value need to update by rest)
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "channelId": 1,
        "rate": 8
    }
]
```

here id is the post id in json.

Now I want to update the data i.e. rate value in the post id 1 from 8 to 10. I have written the following class and url to update the data but I am failed to do so. Here is the code:

update api view urls:

```
path('count/<int:pk>/<int:pk>/update/', CountlUpdateView.as_view()),
```

and here is the view class:

```
class CountlUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CountSerializers

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = Count.objects.filter(pk=id)
        return queryset
```

```
Note:urls path('count/<int:pk>/<int:pk>/update/',CountlUpdateView.as_view()), is not correct.
```

Comment: Have you looked at this link? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/  It explains how to do a POST request in Django which is exactly what it sounds like you need.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you requesting a code review?

Comment: "....but I am failed to do so." What happened? Got any error? Got unexpected result? please clarify the problem

Comment: My urls is not correct path('count/<int:pk>/<int:pk>/update/', CountlUpdateView.as_view()), to map into update view